# MacOS: unable to resize partitions after bootcamp failed

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, macos

I tried to install Win10 with Bootcamp on my MacBook Air running MacOS Sierra 10.12.1. Doing so I changed my main partition in order to create the one for Bootcamp. But when running the Windows setup I had to choose the partition onto which to install Windows and always got an error there. So I tried reformatting the Bootcamp partition within the Windows setup, but also failed.

So I decided to stop and remove the Bootcamp partition. But somehow I can not delete nor merge it with the MacOS partition. The disk utility app says I can not remove the partition because the other one (MacOS) can not be resized. FileVault is deactivated.

So what can I do? By the way, the terminal command line diskutil cs or corestorage list does not work:

```
diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Here's the output from the terminal and from the disk utility app.
[image: disk utility]
[image: terminal diskutil]

The Bootcamp assistant won't allow me to restart the whole process since it can not resize the main partition and it does not let me choose the second partition as a target. Any idea how to cleanup all partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow managed to do it. First, I reformatted all small hidden partitions from disk0s4 to disk0s8 using this command:

```
diskutil erasevolume JHFS+ data5 disk0s4
```

Then I merged all those partitions using this command:

```
diskutil mergePartitions JHFS+ BOOTCAMP disk0s4 disk0s8
```

Finally I used the visual disk utility app to remove the newly created BOOTCAMP partition, which then gave all the empty space to my MacOS partition.